# Does GDB keep a history of previous call stacks?

Tags: gdb

GDB had catched SIGSEGV, I accidentally continued the execution, and now it has catched SIGABRT. Can I still watch the backtrace of the previous call stack (at the moment of SIGSEGV), or is it gone?

Comment: I think `ddd` may do it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor but it's unable to connect to a running GDB session, right?

Comment: It can connect to a running GDB, is it uses GDB as a backend. However it is too late, for it to record anything.

Comment: When I run my tests, I use psedo-random numbers, so that I can re-run under the same conditions.